# mercurial fallback update mechanism

Tags: linux, windows, mercurial

We use mercurial for source control with multiple repositories.

Is there any automatic way to update first on **DEV_USER** branch and if that doesn't exist to update to **default** branch?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selected answer is a great one, but just to put it out there here's what I'd do:

```
hg update DEV_USER || hg update
```

which if you wanted you could put in a mercurial alias

```
[alias]
myupdate = !$HG update $1 || $HG update
```

which could be invoked as `hg myupdate maybe_exists`

Comment: I knew there is a simpler answer and actually was waiting for yours :-)

Comment: Heh, thanks.  Yours is cross platform, so it's probably the better answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
hg up -r "limit(sort(head() & (DEV_USER | default), -branch))"
```

this expression takes heads that belong to either `DEV_USER` or `default`. Then it sorts them by branch name descending - the `DEV_USER` should go first if it exists. Then take only one with `limit`

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know about mercurial revision sets. I added this link for further reference http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets

Comment: It's implicitly stated above, but worth nothing that if `DEV_USER` were called `APP_DEV_USER` this wouldn't work without removing the minus sign.